# Display fetched data into table in React

Tags: reactjs

I am unable to tel why my table has no data. Is it the way I'm calling for the display, `{this.newItems}` or what could it be?

```
export default class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        taskList: []
      };
    }

   
  componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshList();
  
  } 
  //refreshList Function start
  refreshList = () => {
    axios
    .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/list/api/rooms/")
    .then(res => this.setState({ taskList: res.data }))
    .catch(err => alert(err))
  }
  //refreshList Function end
  
  //renderItems Function start
  renderItems = () => {
    const newItems  = this.state.taskList;
    return newItems.map(item => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{item.thing1}</td>
        <td>{item.thing2}</td>
        <td>{item.thing3}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
  //renderItems Function end
  render (){  
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar/>
            <table className="layout container">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>thing1</th>
                  <th>thing2</th>
                  <th>thing3</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {this.newItems}
              </tbody>

            </table>

            <Footer/>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is renderItems call ?

Comment: call `this,renderItems()` instead of this.newItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that inside `<tbody>` tag you are using `this.newItems`, which is a local variable and doesn't exist outside the scope of `renderItems` function.

The piece of code responsible to render the table data is `renderItems` function, which you created but never called.

So you just need to do that:

```
    <tbody>
        {this.renderItems()}
    </tbody>
```

Also, inside the `renderItems` function, there is no need to create additional variable if you are not going to modify it. So it can be written simply as:

```
renderItems = () => {
    return this.state.taskList.map(item => (
      <tr key={item.id}>
        <td>{item.thing1}</td>
        <td>{item.thing2}</td>
        <td>{item.thing3}</td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };
```